# Is it possible to migrate power bi report to tableau report

Tags: powerbi, tableau-api

> I need to migrate a power bi report to tableau report and tableau to power bi report vice versa.
> Is it possible to migrate it manually
> is there any tool to migrate it

Answer (score 0):

Unless something has changed very recently, it's a manual process to migrate. As well as migrating dashboards (where the 2 products are different anyway), there's also the data sources to switch, calculated field to recreate, permissions models to implement, etc. A lot of effort and no automated way to do it as, technologically and architecturally, the products are quite different.

Answer (score 0):

Power BI and Tableau are very different tools, with no easy path to automate migrations.

Typically, you're source data can remain unchanged, but you will have to migrate the connection, any DAX / VizQL and report visualisations manually, working through the specific platforms' implementation.